# How to make lead nitrate from pure lead

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Is it possible to add copper nitrate solution and lead so that a single displacement reaction occurs to yield lead nitrate. I recently melted lead and added cooper nitrate to the molten lead. I then collected the copper nitrate solution I had poured and repeated the process of melting the lead and pouring the solution over it. I figured that eventually the copper will be displaced by the slightly more reactive lead. Will this method yield lead nitrate?

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure of putting copper nitrate to lead. But the common way to produce lead nitrate is to put lead into nitric acid. It will produce lead nitrate and hydrogen gas.

$\ce{Pb + 2HNO_3 -> Pb(NO_3)2 + H_2}$

If you have lead oxide instead of lead it also can priduce lead nitrate by adding to nitric acid

$\ce{PbO + 2HNO_3 -> Pb(NO_3)2 + H2O}$